# CSS Cache Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a site under Laravel based on a template uploaded on Themeforest. I use the CSS proposed by this template. I would like to set up custom CSS rules but I have the impression that Laravel has a cache. No CSS changes are displayed. I have the problem in two cases: if I make a new CSS file or even if I modify an existing CSS file.

- I tried to clear my browser's cache.
- I tried to clear Laravel's cache with artisan views:clear and artisan cache:clear.
- I also checked that my CSS files were included in my Blade file.

This is strange because if I put CSS directives directly into my Blade file as HTML (style=""") it works. But once it's in an external file it doesn't work.

Do you have any leads ?

Comment: The CSS file is in the header and yet nothing works

Comment: what would Laravel have to do with your CSS files that are served by your webserver, not Laravel?

Comment: Please show example of code where you try use css and its didnt work.

Comment: Since my CSS files are loaded by Laravel's Blade template engine, I'm thinking there may be a specific cache system

Comment: What is your Laravel version?

Comment: no your CSS is not loaded by Laravel's Blade template engine ... your browser loads them

Comment: send screen shot of your code in images

Comment: no don't send screen shot of your code in images ... code is text, it belongs as text in the question

Comment: You need to provide more information. It's really unclear what's going on here

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code for the bootstrap cache clear.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

or

```
php artisan optomize
```